# Cannot convert string to Enum type I created

Tags: c#, string, enums

I have an enum:

```
public enum Color
{
    Red,
    Blue,
    Green,
}
```

Now if I read those colors as literal strings from an XML file, how can I convert it to the enum type Color.

```
class TestClass
{
    public Color testColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Now when setting that attribute by using a literal string like so, I get a very harsh warning from the compiler. :D Can't convert from string to Color.

Any help?

```
TestClass.testColor = collectionofstrings[23].ConvertToColor?????;
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```
TestClass.testColor = (Color)Enum.Parse(typeof(Color), collectionofstrings[23]);
```

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type Object to Color(the enum).
What can I do in this case?

Comment: @Sergio Then you missed the explicit cast (Color)

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
TestClass.testColor = (Color)Enum.Parse(typeof(Color), collectionofstrings[23]);
```

See [documentation about Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum_members(VS.80).aspx)

**Edit:** in .NET 4.0 you can use a more type-safe method (and also one that doesn't throw exceptions when parsing fails):

```
Color myColor;
if (Enum.TryParse(collectionofstring[23], out myColor))
{
    // Do stuff with "myColor"
}
```

Comment: It says I can't convert from Object to Color. Any help?

Comment: Then you probably forgot the cast to Color in front of the call to Parse. This is for sure the method to go from string to enum.

Comment: @MattGreer this is a better way of doing it if you *care* when the parse "fails". It's true it won't throw an exception if it can't actually be parsed, but instead it will return whatever the `0` entry in the enum is and you'd have no clue it actually failed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Enum.Parse to convert your string to the correct Color enum value:

```
TestClass.testColor = (Color)Enum.Parse(typeof(Color), collectionofstrings[23], true);
```

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else has said:

```
TestClass.testColor = (Color) Enum.Parse(typeof(Color), collectionofstrings[23]);
```

If you're having an issue because the `collectionofstrings` is a collection of objects, then try this:

```
TestClass.testColor = (Color) Enum.Parse(
    typeof(Color), 
    collectionofstrings[23].ToString());
```